# Should a UserControl's Refresh() method be automatically called when its container's Refresh() method is called?

Tags: user-controls

In a project created in Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2012, I have a form with the following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 m_form2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        m_form2 = new Form2();
        m_form2.Show();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Refreshing form1");
        Refresh();
        m_form2.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Form2 has the following method:

```
    public override void Refresh()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Refreshing Form2");
        base.Refresh();
    }
```

Form2 contains an instance of the RefreshTestControl, which contains this method:

```
    public override void Refresh()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Control is being refreshed.");
        base.Refresh();
    }
```

I expected that my control's overridden Refresh() method would get called automatically when Form2.Refresh() is called, but it's not.  Why not?  Am I doing something wrong, or do I just not understand what happens when a form is refreshed?

Comment: Please tag this `java`, so it can more easily be found and understood

Comment: This not Java.  It is C#.  However, because the question is not about the C# language, I am not going to tag it C# either.